# Using Web Audio API to assign two sounds to two Divs and play each independently via a click event with javascript

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have been picking away at the code linked in the url below and I haven't been able to get anywhere.
I have only managed to reassign the event handler to a small div instead of the whole page. I can't figure out how to tweak this to load more than one sound.

http://www.f1lt3r.com/w3caudio/web-audio-api/basic-examples/low-latency-playback-user-input.html

With the code example below I haven't been able to trigger a sound via a click of a div at all. However this code seems nicer to look at so I would really like to modify this for learning purposes.

```
   var context = new webkitAudioContext(),
        buffer;

    var playAudioFile = function (buffer) {
        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
    };

    var loadAudioFile = (function (url) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('get', 'A.mp3', true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        request.onload = function () {
                context.decodeAudioData(request.response,
                     function(incomingBuffer) {
                         playAudioFile(incomingBuffer);
                     }
                );
        };

        request.send();
    }());





// I added this & it doesn't work



var divElement = document.getElementById("divElement");

divElement.addEventListener("click", playAudioFile , false);


// END of code I added
```

I understand how to create oscillators and connect filter/gain and other nodes. Thus far that is my point of reference when using the API. The XMLHttpRequest processess coupled withe the buffer creation is confusing. I understand what a buffer is and I understand what XMLHttprequest is, but for some reason the process around loading an audio file for playback doesn't seem clear to me, let alone loading more than one which is what I ultimately want to do. I've tried to read the HTML-5 rocks tutorials as well but without working C&P code that I can tweak I can never tell if I'm on the right track. BTW I don't want to use abstracted libraries. I want to learn the API from the ground up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're executing playAudioFile when you click the div. playAudioFile needs a buffer as an argument, or else it won't be able to do what it's supposed to. However, there is no buffer passed when you click the div, the playAudioFile function is executed without a buffer (and is given an event object as an argument instead, but that's not important), and thus no sound.

What you probably want to do is to assign loadAudioFile instead when you click the div. At the moment loadAudioFile is written to execute as the page loads (which is what happens when you wrap your function in parantheses). So I'd update the loadAudioFile function to look like this:

```
var loadAudioFile = function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('get', 'A.mp3', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    request.onload = function () {
            context.decodeAudioData(request.response,
                 function(incomingBuffer) {
                     //HERE is where the playAudioFile function is called, with a buffer to play
                     playAudioFile(incomingBuffer);
                 }
            );
    };

    request.send();
};
```

And then

```
divElement.addEventListener("click", loadAudioFile , false);
```

Now, this makes the app load the mp3 each time you click the div. It could be optimised a lot by just loading it once and saving the buffer for later.

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext(),
    savedBuffer;

var playAudioFile = function () {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = savedBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately
};

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('get', 'A.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function () {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response,
             function(incomingBuffer) {
                 //save the buffer, we'll reuse it
                 savedBuffer = incomingBuffer;
                 //once the file has been loaded, we can start listening for click on the div, and use playAudioFile since it no longer requires a buffer to be passed to it
                 var divElement = document.getElementById("divElement");
                 divElement.addEventListener("click", playAudioFile , false);
             }
        );
};

request.send();
```

Comment: I'm assuming that if I want to load multiple audio files I basically have to repeat this same bulky block of code short of it being abstracted? I'm not experienced enough to tell by looking at it if the developers of the API had something else in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, just repeat the request part. You can wrap it in a function and pass an url with the file you want to load (and replace "A.mp3" with the url variable). You'd then have to store the buffers you receive in some other way, like say an object, for later retrieval.

Comment: I copied the bottom part twice and only one audio file plays. I added a JS fiddle here to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RHR8b/1/  The idea is it will trigger a different file for each div. I think the problem is the audio file is being saved in one buffer and I assume I need more than one for each file. I've tried to remedy this by renaming the various buffer-assigned variables on the second copy but it doesn't seem to be the correct path.

Comment: Note. I got it working but I actually ended having to copy the whole block and modify it. I think I might have misunderstood your directions.  http://jsfiddle.net/N3eQY/