# Connecting a simple gain node to Web Audio API file buffers

Tags: web-audio-api

I can't seem to understand why this isn't working. I have no errors.I have done this using oscillators and it works fine. FYI this is a continuation of this thread: 
[Using Web Audio API to assign two sounds to two Divs and play each independently via a click event with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106769/using-web-audio-api-to-assign-two-sounds-to-two-divs-and-play-each-independently)

Code:

```
<div id="divElement"></div>


<style> 

#divElement{
background-color: orange;
width:70px;
height:100px;
left:143px;
}

</style>

<script>

var context = new webkitAudioContext(),
    savedBuffer;

var playAudioFile = function () {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    var gainNode = context.createGainNode();
    source.buffer = savedBuffer;


 // START OF PROBLEM AREA: Gain not working but file still plays with no errors.

    source.connect(gainNode);           
    gainNode.connect(context.destination);
    gainNode.gain = 0;

 // END OF PROBLEM AREA

    source.noteOn(0); // Play sound immediately


};

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('get', 'audio/A.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function () {
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response,
             function(incomingBuffer) {

                 savedBuffer = incomingBuffer;

                 var divElement = document.getElementById("divElement");
                 divElement.addEventListener("click", playAudioFile , false);
             }
        );
};

request.send();

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `gainNode.gain.value = 0` instead. `gainNode.gain` is an `AudioGain` object, which has the attribute `value`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioGainNode